# How to fix Failed initializing wireless card mon0

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

Interface mon0:

ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device

Failed initializing wireless card(s): mon0

Comment: There's not much for anybody to work with here. You're going to need to describe the problem more thoroughly, including what you've tried to resolve it on your own.

Comment: What wireless card do you have?

Comment: I dont have, but i use wifi from public facilities